# NPM /Install issue with Ionic Pro

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework

Getting any one tell me what this error means - I am getting this when building in Ionic Pro

```
Running: npm install
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for ios-deploy@1.9.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Answer (score 2):

[This Github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14042) has some explanation of the `npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for ___` message. The module in your case is [ios-deploy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ios-deploy). It looks like you're running Linux OS but that module requires darwin (Mac).

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to Ionic, Do you have a suggestion as to how to fix

Comment: If it's not possible to try this on a Mac OS computer, you need to decide whether it's a requirement that you develop your Ionic app for both iOS and Android. If targeting iOS is not a requirement, maybe you can remove that `ios-deploy` dependency from your `package.json` file, although I'm not too familiar with Ionic to begin with so that might not be possible. My next suggestion would be to consider trying React Native instead of Ionic. There's a neat RN framework called [Expo](https://expo.io/) which let's you build iOS apps on Windows or Linux

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are installing package which supports in MacOS, from Linux. I added ios-deploy as an optionalDependency and it is skipped with a warning.
The following change in my package.json file worked for me

`"optionalDependencies": {
    "ios-deploy": "^1.9.4"
},`